# Constructors, Setters, and Getters also helper method

Tags: java

I am having a hard time understanding what a constructor is and my teacher is not very helpful.

I have included part of my code and that is the employee class. I also have a main class too that goes with this. I don't want to include it all because I'm pretty much done with the assignment assuming I'm using constructors and don't really want to share my work.

I was hoping someone could point out if I'm using constructors? I know it sounds silly but I just don't get what a constructor is. I'm supposed to use 3 not including the default. I wrote 2 versions of this program one with a scanner and array and one with predefined array. If I haven't used constructors please advise to what they are. If I have please point out where they are so I can see.

I would really appreciate some help, thank you very much in advance.

Also what is a helper method?

```
public class Employee{ 

    String firstname = ""; 
    String lastname = ""; 
    String phone = ""; 
    String address = "";
    String id = "";
    String title = "";
    String salary = "";



    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(String salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------           
    //ToString Method
    public String toString(){
        return "First Name:" + this.firstname +  "\n" + 
               "Last Name:" + this.lastname + "\n" + 
               "Phone #: " + this.phone +  "\n" +
               "Address: " + this.address +  "\n" + 
               "ID: " + this.id + "\n" + 
               "Title: " + this.title + "\n" + 
               "Salary: " + this.salary;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------       
    //Equals method
    public boolean equals (Employee other){
        return phone.equals(other.phone);
    }
   //------------------------------------------------------------------------       
      //Methods to change 

    public void changePhone(String newPhone) {
        phone = newPhone;
    }
    public void changeId(String newId) {
        id = newId;
    }
    public void changeTitle(String newTitle) {
        title = newTitle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Constructors have the identical name with your Class but no return type. If you dont provide any, the default constructor is  `public Employee(){}`

Comment: I was afraid of that. What do you mean by no return type?

Comment: can they be used with an input array using a scanner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constructor is a method named the same as the class. You don't have any methods named `Employee`, therefore you do not have any constructors.

You can have multiple constructors with different arguments. Since this is the `Employee` class constructors would look like:

```
public class Employee {
    // Default constructor, no arguments.
    public Employee() {
        ...
    }

    // Two argument constructor.
    public Employee(String arg1, int arg2) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The purpose of a constructor is to initialize an object. For this class you could create a no-argument constructor that sets all of the fields to blanks, and a multi-argument one that takes in first name, last name, etc., and initializes the fields to those values.

Notice how the constructors also have no return type. You don't write `public void Employee()`, it's just `public Employee()`. Constructors work like functions that return `void`, but you don't write the `void`. It's part of the special syntax for constructors.

Constructors are called when you use `new`. The arguments to `new` are passed to the appropriate constructor. For instance, you could call the two constructors above when creating two different employee objects:

```
// Call the default constructor.
Employee jack = new Employee();

// Call the two argument constructor.
Employee jill = new Employee("Jill", 42);
```

---

A helper method is an informal term. It's a method that is called by other code and "helps" that code by offloading some of the work.

Let's pretend you have a method that performs steps `A; B; C; D; A; B; C;` in that order. That's a bit repetitive, isn't it? You could move steps `A; B; C;` to a helper method--call it `H`--and then rewrite the first method as `H(); D; H();`. That would be a helper method.

Comment: When I finally understand this how would I test to see if I am actually using a constructor? My program is fully functional I just have to implement 3 constructors.

Comment: @jake  use constructor when you create object with `new` keyword. For instance,  `Employee e = new Employee();`

Answer (score 1):

You are not using any constructors from what I can see.
A construct is an object function that is called when you create a `new` object. You can use this to set default values or take a parameter.

```
class Car
{
private String carName;

public Car(String name)
{
this.carName = name;
}


public void setCarName(String name)
{
this.carName = name;
}

public String getCarName()
{
return this.carName;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sir, you're using getters/setters but no constructors.

Add this to your class (well replace etc. etc. with all your fields :P):

```
public Employee(String firstname, String lastname, etc. etc.){
this.firstname = firstname;
this.lastname = lastname;
//same thing for other fields
}
```

Comment: Sort of accurate. @jake hasn't defined a non-default constructor but is certainly using a constructor if he is using his class. If you don't define a constructor then Java creates one for you, the default constructor. That is why you would still be able to do this: Employee someEmployee = new Employee(), create an employee with default state;

Comment: Well, if the assignement was about using constructors I will exclude the default one from the wanted list, otherwise even a setter/getter POJO like his version will be ok.

Comment: Yes, for sure. I was just clarifying and not criticizing. Understanding the default constructor is important.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors have the identical name with your Class but no return type.

```
public class Employee{ 

    String firstname = ""; 
    String lastname = ""; 
    String phone = ""; 
    String address = "";
    String id = "";
    String title = "";
    String salary = "";

    public Employee(){
        // default constructor
    }

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName){
        // call another constructor
        this(firstName, lastName, this.title);
    }

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String title){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Constructers are used for creating objects with `new` keywords.

```
Employee e1 = new Employee(); // no parameters, use all initialized values;
Employee e2 = new Employee("Bill", "Gatz"); // 2 parameters, assign firstname and last name
```

Answer (score 1):

in your piece of code there's no constructor.

The constructor is a function that is called whenever a class is **instantiated** (i.e. when you use the keyword `new`)

The only syntax allowed for a constructor is

```
public class Employee{

public Employee(){
    //constructor
}

public Employee(String arg){
    //overloaded constructor that takes a string as argument
}
```

There's no return type and it has to have the same name as the parent class (you may also have private constructors, but you'll rarely find them)

the first constructor is called whenever yo write

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
```

and the second when you give arguments to it (in this example strings)

```
Employee employee = new Employee("Employee name");
```

Java chooses automatically which constructor to call based on the arguments you give

Answer (score 0):

When an object is created Java calls the constructor first, since your field variables are marked private there has to be a way of creating an Object initially with values.

So thats what constructors are for. They have the same name as their class, They have no return type

as far as i can see you have no constructor in your class.

Comment: It's a low quality, low effort answer. I'd be glad to remove my downvote if the grammar and spelling are cleaned up and the answer is fleshed out some more.

Comment: Yes please this is a question which can be found all over the Internet in Great depth so why reinvent the Wheel ?